# Can I set up a Raspberry Pi SD card in a phone?

Tags: sd-card, android

So I can't afford a PC, but maybe I can get a Raspberry Pi. I heard about the SD card flashing, is it possible to do it on a smartphone? Download files and flash the SD card or will I need some things to run? Is it possible without having any computer?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This might be of interest: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38107/19949 Note that one can also buy a pre-flashed SD card with NOOBS/raspbian.

Comment: Ghanima Hi it says about he has pc and rest I'm asking to do it without pc would it be possible I'll look into guide sometimes later

Comment: I use a PocketChip for inexpensive portable GNU/Linux needs... builtin wifi, Debian, USB port, GPIO, Touch screen... $69USD...  You can use `wget` or `curl` from the command line to retrieve the latest Raspbian image.

Answer (score 4):

Use Pi card imager found on the android play store.

More info here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=170856

Comment: For custom images it needs a rooted-phone

Answer (score 2):

1. So I can't afford a PC, but maybe I can get a Raspberry Pi.
2. I heard about the SD card flashing, is it possible to do it on a smartphone? Download files and flash the SD card or will I need some things to run?
3. Is it possible without having any computer?

OK dear mate, I have divided Your Question into 3 parts (for my own convenience). First of all, only a Raspberry Pi board (any one, Raspberry Pi A, B, Raspberry Pi-2, even the latest Raspberry Pi-3) is of no use without a means to talk to it, I mean a keyboard, a mouse, a (HDMI)monitor, a SD card reader and a SD card upon which You will install Raspbian OS.

So if You are planing to have Your Raspberry Pi, without any of the above peripherals, You will have to SSH to Your Raspberry Pi, (another issue), or Use VNC (may be from Your smart phone), You will have to edit/modify Files in the Raspbian OS, prior to run it. (May be I am wrong, but) You will need a SD card reader, and a friends PC, (I know You cann't afford, or have a PC, at the time being).
My Question may be confusing, But, If You can't afford all those peripherals, How will You run/use a Raspberry Pi?

So my humble opinion is, If You are purchasing  Raspberry Pi, a monitor, a keyboard, a mouse, better purchase a SD card reader too.

Thanks and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: idk if this will ping u but i know its some kind of a pc I'll buy mouse monitor keyboard etc for it but i won't buy a pc to.setup a pc asking if the things possible on phone i think i found an app for to download the files n phone just  need to format sd card if needed not sure why its needed isn't default sdcards formatted properly? But anyway i think i can figure it out myself but more comments and answers are appreicated

Comment: Ok Mate, I think You should have a look at the following post, 
"Flashing an SD Card from an Android device"
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12098.  I'm sure, its what You are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use raspi card imager to flash os directly to sd card without any need of pc by just using android smartphone.

Comment: What is raspi card imager for android? Where to get it?

Answer (score -2):

Just to do it, I've completely setup an SD from my phone and was successful in running it on a brand new 3 B+. I am using a Samsung Note 8. My image includes Rasbian and Retropie. No PC was used in the process, not once.

Comment: This answers the explicit question (i.e. is it possible), but completely ignores the implicit question of how.